# Python script for creating docker container using Remote API

Tags: python, json, docker

I am trying to create a Docker container with the Docker Remote API using a Python script to do the Post opertion. This is my Python Script:-

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://localhost:4243/containers/create"
payload = {'Hostname':'','User':'','Memory':'0','MemorySwap':'0','AttachStdin':'false','AttachStdout':'t    rue','AttachStderr':'true','PortSpecs':'null','Privileged':    'false','Tty':'false','OpenStdin':'false','StdinOnce':'false','Env':'null','Cmd':['date'],'Dns':'null','Image':'ubuntu','Volumes':{},'VolumesFrom':'','WorkingDir':''}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
print requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).text
```

But when I run the script it shows this error

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type bool
```

What is wrong with my script? I use Requests HTTP library for Python v2.7.5 and Ubuntu 13.10.
I am new to docker and python scripting. Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Try using `True` and `False` instead of the strings `"true"` and `"false"` in your payload dict.

Comment: I tried using True and False. Now it shows this error-           json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, you aren't using the right types.

Specifically:

- boolean values must be `True` or `False`, instead of `"true"` or `"false"`
- `Dns`, `Env`, and `PortSpecs` must be `None` instead of `"null"`
- `Memory` and `MemorySwap` must be `0` instead of `"0"`

You can see all the type definitions in the [API docs for the create command](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/api/docker_remote_api_v1.5/#create-a-container).

Here is a payload that works:

```
payload={
 'AttachStderr': True,
 'AttachStdin': False,
 'AttachStdout': True,
 'Cmd': ['date'],
 'Dns': None,
 'Env': None,
 'Hostname': '',
 'Image': 'ubuntu',
 'Memory': 0,
 'MemorySwap': 0,
 'OpenStdin': False,
 'PortSpecs': None,
 'Privileged': False,
 'StdinOnce': False,
 'Tty': False,
 'User': '',
 'Volumes': {},
 'VolumesFrom': '',
 'WorkingDir': '',
}
```

But somehow, it would be nice if the parser could tell exactly which field could not be parsed :-)

Comment: Yes :) I used the right types and its working Perfectly now. Thanks!